# How to unset modes in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have used this command to use double quotes in identifiers:

```
set session sql_mode='ansi_quotes'
```

Now I want reset:

```
set session sql_mode =""
```

I think will reset all modes but I want reset only this mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You remove the `ansi_quotes` mode by doing another `SET SESSION` command.  In general you might have several mode settings.  If you want to selectively turn off just `ansi_quotes`, the following should do the trick:

```
SET sql_mode = (SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ansi_quotes',''));
```

Read [this article](http://johnemb.blogspot.com.au/2014/09/adding-or-removing-individual-sql-modes.html?m=1) for more detailed information.